# Android Display Image and Text in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, json, horizontalscrollview

So, I have this layouts:

my main.xml (pseudo)

```
<LinearLayout  >
<RelativeLayout> 
    <HorizontalScrollView >
        <LinearLayout

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then list.xml

```
<FrameLayout>
     <ImageView>
     <TextView>
<FrameLayout>
```

How can fill up my display with data from json without using ListView and GridView?
How to iterate the data from my json to display it in the HorizontalScrollView?
Because i want to display it horizontally. I've used GridView and i thought i can customize it. SO, without using ListView and GridView I want to display my data (image and text) horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am used [this](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34).

for the **horizontal listview** like you.

In my case it is work perfect **Horizontal list** view with image,image **select/unselect**,drag and drop and many more.

If you find any problem then let me know.

Comment: how can i implement this one with my JSON and the BaseAdapter?

Comment: this is one type of listview.so you have to create bean/pojo set all json data and used in using adapter

Comment: so it is similar to this [one](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/) but instead of using ListView, it uses the HorizontalListView right?

Comment: i need to create a bean for every activity of my application right? since every activity has different list. It's more like a descendant navigation.

Comment: sure, im going to accept this later. i have to try if it really works. but i have a good feeling that this is the answer i've been looking for.